# Using Cloudant API with IBMCloudCode

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ibm-cloud, cloudant

I have a cloudantDB server and database on it. On my js file, I create IBMCloudCode to call cloudantAPI.

js file:

```
app.value('IBM_CREDENTIALS',{
    APP_ROUTE: 'http://myserver.cloudant.com'
})
.factory('IBMService',['$http','IBM_CREDENTIALS', '$window',function($http,IBM_CREDENTIALS, $window){
    var config = {
      //  applicationId:IBM_CREDENTIALS.APP_ID,
        applicationRoute:IBM_CREDENTIALS.APP_ROUTE,
      //  applicationSecret:IBM_CREDENTIALS.APP_SECRET
    };

    IBMBluemix.initialize(config);
    var ibmCC = IBMCloudCode.initializeService();

    return {
        getProviderById:function(providerId){
          return ibmCC.get("/provider/_all_docs?key="ABC123"&include_docs=true");
        }

    }
}]);
```

But when debug to get API I have a error message : "IBMBluemix.getConfig(...).getBaaSURL is not a function". Please help me to review and give me your thoughts. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to npm, [IBM Cloud Code is currently deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ibmcloudcode).

The corresponding backend services on Bluemix have been completely removed, so CloudCode will not work as expected.

If you continue to have issues, I suggest using something like the [Request library](https://github.com/request/request) to send simple REST requests.

Comment: Thanks for sharing..:)